# Reusable Sync HttpClient Request

Tags: dart, httprequest, dart-async, dart-http

I need a reusable function that makes an HTTP request and awaits for its completion before returning the response as a String.

Here's the main function:

```
main() async {
  var json;
  json = await makeRequest('https://...');
  print(json);
  print('*** request complete ***');
}
```

**(First Case)** This is the reusable function that makes the HTTP request:

```
makeRequest(String url) async {
  var request = await new HttpClient().postUrl(Uri.parse(url));

  // Includes the access token in the request headers.
  request.headers.add(...);

  // Waits until the request is complete.
  var response = await request.close();

  await for (var contents in response.transform(UTF8.decoder)) {
    return contents;
  }
}
```

This works as expected and the output is:

```
// Response contents as a String...
*** request complete ***
```

**(Second Case)** Then I tried to do this and it didn't work:

```
makeRequest(String url) async {
  var request = await new HttpClient().postUrl(Uri.parse(url));

  // Includes the access token in the request headers.
  request.headers.add(...);

  // Waits until the request is complete.
  var response = await request.close();

  var json = '';
  await response.transform(UTF8.decoder).listen((contents) {
    // At first I tried to return contents here, but then I added onDone().
    json += contents;
  }, onDone: () {
    return json;
  });

  return json;
}
```

I've tried defining the function within `listen` with `async` and `await`, returning `contents` within `listen` without `onDone()`, but the output is the same:

```
// Empty line.
*** request complete ***
// Waits a few seconds doing nothing before terminating...
```

Does anyone know why the second case doesn't work?

**EDIT:**

After updating the code it does what it was supposed to do, but takes a few seconds before terminating execution:

```
Future<String> twitterRequest(String url) async {
  var request = await new HttpClient().postUrl(Uri.parse(url));

  // Includes the access token in the request headers.
  request.headers.add(...);

  // Waits until the request is complete.
  var response = await request.close();

  var json = '';
  await for (var contents in response.transform(UTF8.decoder)) {
    json += contents;
    // Putting a break here produces the same output but terminates immediately (as wanted).
  }

  return json;
}
```

Output:

```
// Prints response contents...
*** request complete ***
// Takes a few seconds before execution terminates. With the break the code terminates immediately.
```

**EDIT2:**

After submitting [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/24045), I found out that instances of the `HttpClient` have a connection pool and keep persistent connections by default, which keeps the Dart VM alive. Please consult the issue page to find out about the possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably caused by the `await` before the `response.transform`.

You might want something like

```
  return response.transform(UTF8.decoder).join('');
```

The pause is not related to `makeRequest()`. The Dart VM seems to wait for something before it exits. Adding `exit(0);` as last line in `main()` makes the  application exit immediately.

**Update**

According to the response on the [Dart SDK issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/24045#issuecomment-130567616)

> This is caused by the HttpClient instance having a connection pool
>   which can keep the Dart VM alive. There are two ways of avoiding this:
>
> 1) Close the HttpClient explicitly
>   2) Use non-persistent connections

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert' show UTF8;
import 'dart:io';

Future main() async {
  await makeRequest();
  print('end of main');
}

Future makeRequest() async {
  var client = new HttpClient();
  var request = await client.postUrl(Uri.parse('https://example.com'));
  var response = await request.close();
  var contents = await response.transform(UTF8.decoder).join();
  print(contents);
  client.close();  // Close the client.
}
```

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert' show UTF8;
import 'dart:io';

Future main() async {
  await makeRequest();
  print('end of main');
}

Future makeRequest() async {
  var request = await new HttpClient().postUrl(Uri.parse('https://example.com'));
  request.persistentConnection = false;  // Use non-persistent connection.
  var response = await request.close();
  var contents = await response.transform(UTF8.decoder).join();
  print(contents);
}
```

Comment: That is similar to my first case, so it works, but I guess there is no other way to do this.

Comment: Right, I didn't look closer to your first case because it didn't cause problems. You could use a Completer in your 2nd case but you don't really gain anything but raise the complexity unnecessarily.

Comment: However, with his solution, it prints the response contents, then `*** request complete ***`, and then it takes a few seconds without doing anything before the execution terminates. Putting a `break` inside the `for` solves this, but doesn't seem very nice. Anyone knows why this happens?

Comment: Inserting `break;` is pointless. Can you please update your question with your entire current code?

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow. Do you have a public URL to test it with?

Comment: Thanks. And not really. I'm making requests to Twitter with a private key, sorry.

Comment: The pause is weird. I don't know what causes it. Maybe a bug in the VM. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I was already using `exit(0)`, and like you said this is probably a bug. I'm going to report it.